# Why do I get this error when I try to add these arrays in C?

Tags: c

Basically, I'm trying to create another array to save the sum of the number in the first position in "arreglo1" with the last one in "arreglo2" (3+1), but I get an error at time of compiling that says "expression must have pointer-to-object type but it has type int". What am I doing wrong? ;(

```
#include <stdio.h>
int funcion1(int arreglo1,int arreglo2);
int main()
{
int arreglo1[5]={3,5,1,4,-2};
int arreglo2[5]={8,7,2,5,1};
funcion1 (arreglo1,arreglo2);    
}
int funcion1(int arreglo1,int arreglo2){
    int arreglo3[]={};
    int n=5;
    int i;
    int suma;
    for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        arreglo3[i]= arreglo1[i]+arreglo2[n-1];
    }
    for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("%d",arreglo3[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't spam tags.

Comment: The argument `int arreglo1` is a single `int` value, not an array or a pointer (and you need pointers here).

Comment: Also `int arreglo3[]={};` is invalid, as it's a zero-sized array and those are not allowed. Remember that C doesn't have dynamic arrays. Actually, you don't even *need* the `arreglo3` array, just print the result directly in the first loop.

Comment: Ok,so, how should I write it? ._.

Comment: "but I get an error at time of compiling that says "expression must have pointer-to-object type but it has type int"" Well, *do you understand what it means*? Do you know what an *expression* is? Can you tell which expression it's talking about? The error says that it is an integer ("has type int"). Do you see why this is the case? It says that it must instead be a pointer ("have pointer-to-object type"). Do you understand why?

Comment: Hint: when you write `funcion1 (arreglo1,arreglo2);`, what is the type of `arreglo1`? What is the type of `arreglo2`? Where you write `int funcion1(int arreglo1,int arreglo2){`, what do you think this means? In particular, what does the `int` in `int arreglo1` mean? Now, think carefully about what the code should do. Which part is wrong - the call to the function, or the prototype of the function? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also beginner so please tell me if i am wrong.

The problem here is that you are defining the function with:

```
int fuction1(int aareglo1, int arreglo2);
```

You are defining that the function takes an integer as an input, but you are giving an array as an input, so the correct code should be:

```
int function1(int arrenglo1[], int arrenglo2[]);
```

And there is also a problem with its logic, you are giving the value to arrenglo3 as:

```
arrenglo3[i] = arrenglo1[i] + arrenglo2[n-1];
```

Whereas, it should be:

```
arrenglo3[i] = arrenglo1[i] + arrenglo2[n-i-1];
```

I have modified the code and it compiles correctly(atleast in my compiler):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int funcion1(int arreglo1[],int arreglo2[]);

int main()
{
    int arreglo1[5]={3,5,1,4,-2};
    int arreglo2[5]={8,7,2,5,1};
    funcion1 (arreglo1,arreglo2);    
}
int funcion1(int arreglo1[],int arreglo2[]){
    int arreglo3[5];
    int n=5;
    int i;
    int suma;
    for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        arreglo3[i]= arreglo1[i]+arreglo2[n-i-1];
    }
    for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",arreglo3[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but it unwise to _presume_ that the OP wants to step backwards through the 2nd array... Better to ask that as a question, first, before providing code that the OP has not clearly indicated as the intention. Still, a pretty good answer, imho. `:-)`

Comment: Actually, that is what I wanted to do. Ty very much <3

Comment: Sorry, i read it wrong 

Answer (score 1):

`int arreglo1` suggests `arreglo1` is an integer.
However, you have passed in an array.

Modify your `funcion1` to take a pointer to ints, as so:

```c
int funcion1(int *arreglo1, int *arreglo2);
```

after that, this line:

```c
int arreglo3[]={};
```

creates a zero-length array, you want 5 items, so write:

```c
int arreglo3[5];
```

then actually compute `suma` and return it.